# How to datenow minus datetime MySQL with PHP in second

Tags: php, mysql

i want to minus purchase date with datenow. i have table named **count_sec** :

```
|user_id|   purchasedate    |second|
|   1   |2015-06-06 08:36:05|      |
|   2   |2015-06-06 08:36:15|      |
```

example time now is **2015-06-06 08:37:00**
what is the code if i am want the code to update the **second** to:

```
|user_id|   purchasedate    |second|
|   1   |2015-06-06 08:36:05|  55  |
|   2   |2015-06-06 08:36:15|  45  |
```

thank you

EDIT
i have already create this php, but the code is not work, how to fix?

```
<?php
require 'database/db.php';

$selectprchsdate = $mysqli->query("SELECT purchasedate FROM count_sec");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectprchsdate);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$result = $date - $row['purchasedate'];

$mysqli->query("UPDATE count_sec
                SET second = '".$result."'");

?>
```

Comment: You can use PHP's class DateTime and method diff for this. When looping through the results, create a DateTime object for the purchase date and calculate the difference between the current date. Check DateTime in the PHP manual for further details.

Comment: Storing `second` column in the table is a *poor* design choice, because the stored value is going to be old as soon as you store it, and you are going to be continuously cranking unnecessary transactions against the database to try to keep that value updated. **Do not do this.** Do not store **`second`** column in the table and continually update it. That's the wrong way to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve. (I've tried to explain this in my answer, below.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` function like below. See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), purchasedate)
from count_sec;
```

(OR) if you want to `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE count_sec SET `second` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), purchasedate);
```

Per your comment, if you want to delay for 5 minutes then either you can use

`SLEEP(seconds)` function

(OR)

Wrap your updation code in a stored procedure and run that in every 5 minutes (probably using some scheduler job)

Comment: Not sure if I have understood your question?

Comment: Whoever downvoting, post a comment stating the reason as well.

Comment: This answer recommends the *wrong* approach; running a stored procedure every five minutes to update every row in the table; continually chasing a value that is wrong as soon as it's assigned. (It's reasonable to show an example `UPDATE` statement to help explain what's going on with the OP code (fetching a single row, performing a calculation, and updating every row in the table with an identical value.) But... recommending storing the calculated value, and updating every row in the table every five minutes is the **wrong answer** to whatever problem OP is really trying to solve. (**-1**)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the SQL query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(purchasedate) as second from countsec
```

or this:

```
SELECT TO_SECONDS(NOW()) - TO_SECONDS(purchasedate) as second from countsec;
```

From [MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: This is the right approach to solving the problem. The answer to OP question is.. **do not store** the calculated value in the table, and continually chase that with updates of every row in the table. The right answer is to calculate the value at the time the row is pulled from the table.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use

```
// get current date and time
$now = new DateTime();
// create DateTime object for purchase date
$purchaseDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['purchasedate']);
// calculate seconds
$seconds = $now->getTimeStamp() - $purchaseDate->getTimeStamp();
```

But the SQL solution suits this question better.

Comment: This is a right answer because it dis-recommends continuous updates of a unnecessary column on every row in the table. **+1**. The calculation can be done in PHP as well as SQL... one the thing to be cognizant of is the timezone of the MySQL connection. In a SQL expression, `NOW()` and `purchasedate` are evaluated in the same timezone. With PHP, timezone of `purchasedate` is from database server, `$now` could be different timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding why you need to store this in a column in the table. As soon as it's stored, the value is old, and it will need to be updated again. (Don't do this.) But setting that issue aside for a moment...

As to why your code isn't "working"... your `UPDATE` statement is updating *every* row in the table. You've previously fetched *one* row from the table, and then calculated one value, and then the `UPDATE` statement doesn't have a WHERE clause to identify *which* row(s) you want to update, so every row gets updated with the same value. That's a big part of why your code isn't working.

And, there's no need to run a `SELECT` statement before you run an `UPDATE`. If you want to update all rows in the table, you set the column to an expression that returns the number of seconds between the current date and time and the date and time stored in `purchasedate` column.

One convenient way to do that is to use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function to convert each of the DATETIME values into an integer value (number of seconds), and subtract them. For example:

```
  UPDATE count_sec 
     SET `second` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(purchasedate)
```

As an alternative, you could use the TIMESTAMPDIFF function for an equivalent result:

```
  UPDATE count_sec 
     SET `second` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),purchasedate)
```

---

But back to the issue of why this is wrong. You **do not want to store** `second` column in the table.

When you run a `SELECT` statement to return a row from the table, the value in this column is going to old.

Instead, you could just return a **calculated value**, calculated as of the time the SELECT statement runs, by including one of those expressions in the `SELECT` list. For example:

```
  SELECT user_id
       , purchasedate
       , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(purchasedate) AS `calc_second`
       , `second` AS `old_stored_value`
    FROM count_sec
   ORDER BY user_id
```

The point I'm trying to emphasize here... do **not** store the `second` value in the table. You'll be chasing it, and continuously updating every row in table, whether that's every five minutes or every five seconds. And the stored value is always going to be "old".

Why do you need that?  If you want to find out which rows in the table have `second` between 60 and 120, for example, if you intend to run this query:

```
 SELECT user_id 
   FROM count_sec
  WHERE second > 120 
    AND second <= 60
```

You could just as easily rewrite that based on `purchasedate`

```
 SELECT user_id 
   FROM count_sec
  WHERE purchasedate >   NOW() - INTERVAL 120 SECOND
    AND purchasedate <=  NOW() - INTERVAL 60 SECOND
```

And, you won't be "chasing" continuous updates of the rows in the table, generating rollbackup, recording changes in the InnoDB log, writing the UPDATE statements in the binary logs. If you are running replication slaves, those statements have to be read from the log and re-executed on the slaves. All in all, storing `second` is just a poor design choice.